# pairs of rows with the highest string similarity

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, string, dataframe

So i have this dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'id': [1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4],
     'name':['ada','aad','ada','ada','dddd','fdd','ccc','cccd','ood','aaa','aaa','aar','rrp']
    ,'amount':[2,-12,12,-12,5,-5,2,3,-5,3,-10,10,-10]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d)
df1
    id  name    amount
0   1   ada      2
1   1   aad     -12
2   1   ada      12
3   1   ada    -12
4   2   dddd    5
5   2   fdd    -5
6   3   ccc     2 
7   3   cccd    3
8   3   ood    -5
9   4   aaa     3
10  4   aaa    -10
11  4   aar     10
12  4   rrp    -10
```

First i want to find the matching positive for negative amounts per id, which i do through this:

```
def match_pos_neg(df):
    return df[df["amount"].isin(-df["amount"])]

df1 = df1.groupby("id").apply(match_pos_neg).reset_index(0, drop=True)
df1
    id  name  amount
1   1   aad   -12
2   1   ada   12
3   1   ada   -12
4   2   dddd    5
5   2   fdd    -5
10  4   aaa   -10
11  4   aar    10
12  4   rrp   -10
```

Next thing i want to do is to get only the pairs of matching pos and neg numbers that also have the highest similarity in the string column 'name'.So if an id has two other negative numbers that match with the positive i want to isolate the pairs with the highest similarity per id, so i want my desired output to be like this:

```
 id  name  amount
2   1   ada   12
3   1   ada   -12
4   2   dddd    5
5   2   fdd    -5
10  4   aaa   -10
11  4   aar    10
```

I guess i have to use some type of string similarity index like sequencematcher or jaccard etc., but i am not sure how to work around this. Any help on how to get my desired output would be very much appreciated.

Comment: If first row is `1   ada      12` need in ouput both pairs for id=1 ?

Comment: For id=1 , i only need this this pair as it has the highest str similarity:    `2  1   ada   12 , 3   1   ada   -12`

Comment: what similarity method? jaccard? how do you want the output to look like?

Comment: @Tomer S Yes jaccard is fine. The desired output is  on my original post(last dataframe).

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

please notice you can change the information you print as you wish, just need to edit the return values from the function create_sim

```
import pandas as pd
from operator import itemgetter

d = {'id': [1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4],
     'name':['ada','aad','ada','ada','dddd','fdd','ccc','cccd','ood','aaa','aaa','aar','rrp']
    ,'amount':[2,-12,12,-12,5,-5,2,3,-5,3,-10,10,-10]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d)

def match_pos_neg(df):
    return df[df["amount"].isin(-df["amount"])]

df1 = df1.groupby("id").apply(match_pos_neg).reset_index(0, drop=True)

print(df1)


def split(word):
    return [char for char in word]


def DistJaccard(str1, str2):
    l1 = set(split(str1))
    l2 = set(split(str2))
    return float(len(l1 & l2)) / len(l1 | l2)


def create_sim(df, idx):
    idx_id = df['id'].values[idx]
    idx_amount = df['amount'].values[idx]
    idx_name = df['name'].values[idx]
    df_t = df.loc[df['id'] == idx_id]
    pos = [i for i in list(df_t['amount']) if i > 0] or None
    neg = [i for i in list(df_t['amount']) if i < 0] or None
    if pos and neg:
        l = [x for x in list(df_t['amount']) if x == idx_amount * -1]
        if len(l) > 0:
            df_t = df.loc[df['amount'] == idx_amount * -1]
            compare_list = list(df_t['name'])
            list_results = []
            for item in compare_list:
                sim = DistJaccard(idx_name, item)
                list_results.append((item, sim))
            return max(list_results, key=itemgetter(1))
    return None

count = 0
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    res = create_sim(df1, count)
    if res:
        print(f"The most similar word of {row['name']} is {res[0]} with similarity of {res[1]}")
    else:
        print(f"No similar words of {row['name']}")
    count+=1
```

**Edit:**

In order to make a DF with the results you can change it to this:

```
count = 0
item1_id = []
item1_row = []
item1_name = []
item2_id = []
item2_row = []
item2_name = []
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    res = create_sim(df1, count)
    item1_id.append(row['id'])
    item1_row.append(count)
    item1_name.append(row['name'])
    if res:
        row_idx = df1.loc[(df1['id'] == res[2]) & (df1['name'] == res[0]) & (df1['amount'] != row['amount']), "name"].index.tolist()
        item2_id.append(row['id'])
        item2_row.append(row_idx[0])
        item2_name.append(res[0])
    else:
        item2_id.append(None)
        item2_row.append(None)
        item2_name.append(None)
    count+=1


final = pd.DataFrame(item1_id, columns=['item 1 id'])
final['item 1 row'] = item1_row
final['item 1 name'] = item1_name
final['item 2 id'] = item2_id
final['item 2 row'] = item2_row
final['item 2 name'] = item2_name

print(final)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort!  How can i just return the relevant rows as a dataframe rather than a print? Like just the relevant pairs of matching positive /negative values which have the highest similarity on the name ?

Comment: see the edited answer

Comment: Hi and thank you for helping. Maybe i am missing something but shouldn't 'item 1 id' be in the same column as 'item 2 id' and the same with the 'item 1 name' and 'item 2 name' and so on. Now, the item 2 columns are only filled with None.

Comment: Ideally i would like the df to be as my desired output df

Comment: Btw i get an error `IndexError: tuple index out of range` for this line `row_idx = df1.loc[(df1['user_id'] == res[2]) & (df1['name'] == res[0]) & (df1['amount'] != row['amount']), "name"].index.tolist()` . I guess it's the  `df1['user_id'] == res[2]`?